# How to document a function that returns specific values?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm trying to document the following method that returns only three values : 'active', 'inactive' or 'blocked' .

**Javascript code :**

```
/**
 * Returns the current post status.
 * @return {string} the current status: 'inactive', 'active' or 'blocked'.
 */
function getStatus() {
    if (this.status === 0) return 'inactive';
    if (this.status === 1) return 'active';
    if (this.status === 2) return 'blocked';
}
```

Is there a way to specify the returned value ? Maybe something like :

```
@return {string=('inactive'|'active'|'blocked')} the current status.
```

If not, how should I do that ?

Comment: Have you considered using TypeScript or Flow? If it's stronger typing you want then that might be something to consider.

Comment: @E.Sundin thank you for the comment, I just want to use Jsdoc for documentation purpose only.

Comment: @E.Sundin is that possible in TypeScript?

Comment: @E.Sundin I mean, is there an option in TypeScript or Flow to generate html documentation ?

Comment: @CryptoBird - Just a heads up, if you need to, you can edit your comments instead of posting new ones.

Comment: Personally I have yet to find a use for such tools so I'm not aware what exists. [Here's two typescript examples](https://jsfiddle.net/p7bdsnp1/)

Comment: @E.Sundin your code is AWESOME , and I just found this [tool](http://typedoc.org), but I don't know if it's good or not.
I think I should start learning Typescript .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in JSDoc, and the only solution that I can think of is using the [@enum](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-enum.html) tag like so :

```
/**
 * Post status.
 * @readonly
 * @enum {string}
 */
var STATUS = {
    /** The post is inactive. */
    INACTIVE: 'inactive',
    /** The post is active. */
    ACTIVE: 'active',
    /** The post is blocked. */
    BLOCKED: 'blocked'
};

/**
 * Returns the current post status.
 * @return {STATUS} the current status.
 */
function getStatus() {
    if (this.status === 0) return STATUS.INACTIVE;
    if (this.status === 1) return STATUS.ACTIVE;
    if (this.status === 2) return STATUS.BLOCKED;
}
```

**JSDoc result :**

[image: Result]